# HttpServletRequest object in Spring webflow?

Tags: spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

How to get `HttpServletRequest` object in `FlowController`?

I am trying to retrieve request object from `getNativeRequest()` method,But it is not giving HttpServletRequest object.

```
(HttpServletRequest)RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext().getExternalContext().getNativeRequest()
```

I followed above approach, It's returning `SRTServletRequest` object.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but `SRTServletRequest` implements `HttpServletRequest`, so you should just be able to cast it.

Comment: Skaffman:Yes your right,but even if i do type casting with the HttpServletRequest object,it's not returning me HttpServletRequest object,that's the reason i am not able to retrieve any values in jsp page.,it simply returning null values.